# Issues with markers on Google Maps API - not always loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a website with Google Maps API, particularly with @ubilabs/google-maps-react-hooks.
I'm not very experienced so I'm having some difficulties understanding why there's an issue.
When I load the website (either locally or online) the markers don't always show up. It could be on loading the site at first or when I refresh, they disappear and reapper upon new refreshing of the page. This never happens if I have my developer tools open (docked or undocked) and I can't figure out why! I've been trying for days.

index.txs

```
import { GoogleMapsProvider } from '@ubilabs/google-maps-react-hooks';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import { useGeoReportState } from '../../context/GeoReportContext';
import { useMapContext, useMapDispatch } from '../../context/MapContext';
import { options } from './MapElements';
import TestMap from './TestMap';

const Index = () => {
    const [mapContainer, setMapContainer] = useState<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

    const mapDispatch = useMapDispatch();
    const mapState = useMapContext();
    const reportState = useGeoReportState();
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    const onLoad = useCallback((map: any) => {
        mapDispatch.setMap(map);
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    }, [reportState]);
    return (
        <>
        <div className='flex flex-col w-full h-full'>
            <GoogleMapsProvider
                mapOptions={options(mapState)}
                googleMapsAPIKey={process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY as string}
                mapContainer={mapContainer}
                version='beta'
                onLoadMap={onLoad}
                libraries={['places']}
            >
                <TestMap />
                <div ref={(node) => setMapContainer(node)} style={{ height: '100vh' }} />
            </GoogleMapsProvider>
        </div> 


    </>
    );
};

export default Index;
```

TestMap.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, SetStateAction } from 'react';
import { useGeoReportState } from '../../context/GeoReportContext';
import { useMapContext } from '../../context/MapContext';
import { findMode, formSubmitGeoCoder, getSoilTypeColor } from '../../utils/Util';
import Navbar from '../Navbar';
import { notificationHandler, surveyLengthHandler } from '../../utils/ContextHandlers';
import { MarkerClusterer, SuperClusterAlgorithm } from '@googlemaps/markerclusterer';
import Icon from '../../img/point.png';
import FileSubmit from '../Form/FileSubmit';
import Form from '../Form/Form';
import ThankYou from '../Form/ThankYou';
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons';
import { AiOutlineLeft, AiOutlineRight, AiOutlineReload } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { GeoReport, Survey } from '../../types/GeoReportTypes';
import { SurveyData } from '../../types/SurveyTypes';
import { useNotificationDispatch } from '../../context/NotificationContext';
import { useSurveyDispatch } from '../../context/SurveyContext';
import PointData from '../Form/PointData';
import { useGoogleMap } from '@ubilabs/google-maps-react-hooks';

const TestMap: React.FC = () => {

    const geoReportState = useGeoReportState();
    const notificationDispatch = useNotificationDispatch();
    const mapState = useMapContext();
    const surveyDispatch = useSurveyDispatch();
    const map = useGoogleMap();

    let formData = {};

    const [showFileSubmit, setShowFileSubmit] = useState(false);
    const [showSliderForms, showSlider] = useState(false);
    const [showThankYouForms, setShowThankYou] = useState(false);
    const [surveys, setSurveys] = useState<Survey[]>([]);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>();
    const [thisMarkers, setThisMarkers] = useState<google.maps.Marker[]>([]);
    const [circles, setCircles] = useState<google.maps.Circle[]>([]);
    const [pointDataArray, setPointDataArray] = useState<GeoReport | null>(null);
    const [distanceBetween, setDistanceBetween] = useState<number | null>(null);
    const [surveyNumber, setSurveyNumber] = useState(surveys.length + 1);
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
    const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] =useState<string>();

    const incrementCount = () => {
        setSurveyNumber(surveyNumber + 1);
    };

    const resetCount = () => {
        setSurveyNumber(1);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!map) return;
        if (thisMarkers.length == 0) {
            Object.entries(geoReportState.map).map(([, reports]) => {
                addMarkers(undefined, reports, thisMarkers, setThisMarkers, setPointDataArray);
                addCircles(undefined, setPointDataArray, reports, circles, setCircles);
            });
        }
        thisMarkers.forEach(marker => {
            marker.setMap(map);
        });
    }, [mapState]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!map) return;

        map.addListener('zoom_changed', () => {
            if (map.getZoom()! >= 11) {
                thisMarkers.forEach(marker => {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                });
                circles.forEach(circle => {
                    circle.setMap(map);
                });
            }
            if (map.getZoom()! < 11) {
                thisMarkers.forEach(marker => {
                    marker.setMap(map);
                });
                circles.forEach(circle => {
                    circle.setMap(null);
                });
            }
        });

    }, [map?.getZoom()]);

    thisMarkers.forEach(marker => {
        marker.addListener('click', () => {
            if (showSliderForms === true) {
                showSlider(false);
            }
        });
    });

    const handleOpenSlider = () => {
        showSlider(!showSliderForms);
        if (pointDataArray) {
            handleClosePointData();
        }
    };

    const handleOpenFileSubmit = () => {
        if (surveys.length === 0) {
            notificationHandler(2, 'Por favor introduza valores válidos', notificationDispatch);
        } else {
            setShowFileSubmit(!showFileSubmit);
        };
    };

    const handleOpenThankYou = () => {
        setShowThankYou(!showThankYouForms);
    };

    const handleClosePointData = () => {
        setPointDataArray(null);
        setDistanceBetween(null);
    };

    const handleSubmitNew = () => {
        setShowThankYou(!showThankYouForms);
        setShowFileSubmit(!showFileSubmit);
        setSurveys([]);
        resetCount();
        setSelectedFile(null);
        setSelectedImage('');
    };

    const handleExit = () => {
        setShowThankYou(!showThankYouForms);
        setShowFileSubmit(!showFileSubmit);
        showSlider(!showSliderForms);
        setSurveys([]);
        resetCount();
        setSelectedFile(null);
        setSelectedImage('');
    };

    const handleAddSurvey = (event: { preventDefault: () => void; }, lat: number, lng: number, nFreatico: boolean, inFreatico: number, nSPT: boolean, table: SurveyData[]) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (lat === 0 || lng === 0 || lat === undefined || lng === undefined || table.length === 0 || (nFreatico === true && (inFreatico === undefined || inFreatico === 0))) {
            notificationHandler(2, 'Por favor introduza valores válidos', notificationDispatch);
        } else {
            if(nSPT) {
                table.map(e => e.spt1 = 1000);
            }
            if (nFreatico === true) {
                const dummy = {
                    lat: lat,
                    lng: lng,
                    nFreatico: nFreatico,
                    inFreatico: inFreatico,
                    table: table,
                };
                surveys.push(dummy);
            } else {
                const dummy = {
                    lat: lat,
                    lng: lng,
                    nFreatico: nFreatico,
                    inFreatico: 0,
                    table: table,
                };
                surveys.push(dummy);
            };
            setSurveys([...surveys]);
            incrementCount();
            notificationHandler(1, 'Sondagem submetida com sucesso', notificationDispatch);
            surveyLengthHandler(surveys.length, surveyDispatch);
        }
    };

    const handleClearSurveys = (event: { preventDefault: () => void; }) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setSurveys([]);
        resetCount();
    };

    const handleFileInput = (e: any, type: number) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        if (type === 1) {
            if (file) {
                if (file.type === 'application/pdf') {
                    setSelectedFile(file);
                } else {
                    notificationHandler(
                        2,
                        'Por favor seleciona um ficheiro tipo PDF',
                        notificationDispatch,
                    );
                }
            }
        } else if (selectedImage) {
            setSelectedImage(file);
        } 
        // else {
        //  notificationHandler(
        //      2,
        //      'Por favor seleciona uma imagem do tipo PNG ou JPEG',
        //      notificationDispatch
        //  );
        //}
    };

    const handleUploadPDF = (e: any, filename: string) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (selectedFile) {
            const formPDFData = new FormData();
            formPDFData.append('filename', filename);
            formPDFData.append('file', selectedFile);
            fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND + '/api/drive', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formPDFData
            });
                //.then((response) => (console.log(response)))
                //.catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }
    };

    const handleUploadImage = (e: any, filename: string) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (selectedImage) {
            const formImgData = new FormData();
    //      formImgData.append('filename', filename);
            formImgData.append('image', selectedImage);
    //      fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND + '/api/drive/image', {
    //          method: 'POST',
    //          body: formImgData,
    //      })
    //          .then((response) => console.log(response))
    //          .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }
    };

    const handleSubmitForm = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void; }) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!surveys[0]) {
            notificationHandler(
                2,
                'Não é possível submeter sem qualquer sondagem',
                notificationDispatch
            );
        }

        const lat = surveys[0].lat;
        const lng = surveys[surveys.length - 1].lng;

        const { adress, placeId } = await formSubmitGeoCoder(Number(lat), Number(lng), notificationDispatch);

        if(email) {
            if (selectedFile) {
                const fileName = selectedFile.name;
                const editedName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length - 4);
                if (selectedImage) {
                //    const oldImgName = selectedImage.name;
                //    const imgExtension = oldImgName.substring(oldImgName.length - 4, oldImgName.length);
                //    const imgName = `logo_${editedName}${imgExtension}`;
                    formData = { adress, placeId, lat, lng, email, surveys, fileName, selectedImage };
                } else {
                    formData = { adress, placeId, lat, lng, email, surveys, fileName };
                }
                const requestOptions = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: JSON.stringify(formData)
                };
                const response = await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND + '/api/report', requestOptions);
                if (response.ok) {
                    handleOpenThankYou();
                    setSurveys([]);
                    resetCount();
                    handleUploadPDF(e, selectedFile.name);
                    if (selectedImage) {
                    //    const oldImgName = selectedImage.name;
                    //    const imgExtension = oldImgName.substring(oldImgName.length - 4, oldImgName.length);
                    //    const imgName = `logo_${editedName}${imgExtension}`;
                       handleUploadImage(e, selectedImage);
                    };
                }
                if (!response.ok) {
                    notificationHandler(
                        2,
                        'Erro',
                        notificationDispatch
                    );
                }

            } else {
                notificationHandler(
                    2,
                    'Para validação do relatório iremos necessitar do mesmo em formato PDF',
                    notificationDispatch
                );
            }
        } else {
            notificationHandler(
                2,
                'Insira um e-mail para poder submeter os dados',
                notificationDispatch
            ); 
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className='flex flex-col w-full h-full'>
                <Navbar setPointDataArray={setPointDataArray} setDistanceBetween={setDistanceBetween} />
                {showSliderForms ? (
                    <>
                        <div className='z-30'>
                            <div className='bg-white sm:absolute sm:right-0 h-auto max-h-full sm:h-full sm:w-[40%] overflow-y-scroll'>
                                {showThankYouForms ? (
                                    <>
                                        <ThankYou />
                                        <div className='justify-center mb-5 items-center flex space-x-2'>
                                            <button
                                                className='bg-blue-helica w-40 h-10 rounded-md text-xs text-white p-1'
                                                onClick={handleSubmitNew}
                                            >
                                                Submeter novo estudo
                                            </button>
                                            <button
                                                className='bg-blue-helica w-40 h-10 rounded-md text-xs text-white p-1'
                                                onClick={handleExit}
                                            >
                                                Sair
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </>
                                ) : (
                                    <>
                                        <button
                                            type='button'
                                            className='bg-white border ml-4 mt-4'
                                            onClick={handleOpenSlider}
                                        >
                                            <IconContext.Provider
                                                value={{
                                                    color: '#000000',
                                                    className: 'h-6 sm:h-9 w-6 sm:w-9',
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                <AiOutlineRight />
                                            </IconContext.Provider>
                                        </button>
                                        <form className='h-auto'>
                                            {showFileSubmit ? (
                                                <>
                                                    <FileSubmit setEmail={setEmail} surveys={surveys} handleFileInput={handleFileInput} selectedFile={selectedFile} selectedImage={setSelectedImage} />
                                                    <div className='justify-center mb-5 items-center flex space-x-2'>
                                                        <button
                                                            className='bg-blue-helica w-40 h-10 rounded-md text-xs text-white p-1'
                                                            onClick={() => {
                                                                handleOpenFileSubmit();
                                                            }}
                                                        >
                                                            Passo Anterior
                                                        </button>
                                                        <button
                                                            className='bg-blue-helica w-40 h-10 rounded-md text-xs text-white p-1'
                                                            onClick={(event) => {
                                                                handleSubmitForm(event);
                                                            }}
                                                        >
                                                            Enviar
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </>
                                            ) : (
                                                <>
                                                    <Form handleOpenFileSubmit={handleOpenFileSubmit} handleAddSurvey={handleAddSurvey} handleClearSurveys={handleClearSurveys} surveyNumber={surveyNumber} />
                                                </>
                                            )}
                                        </form>
                                    </>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </>
                ) : (
                    <>
                        {pointDataArray ? (
                            <>
                                <div className='z-30'>
                                    <div className='bg-transparent right-[35%] absolute top-auto mt-3 h-auto max-h-full w-auto'>
                                        <button
                                            type='button'
                                            className='bg-white border'
                                            onClick={handleOpenSlider}
                                        >
                                            <IconContext.Provider
                                                value={{
                                                    color: '#000000',
                                                    className: 'h-6 sm:h-9 w-6 sm:w-9',
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                <AiOutlineLeft />
                                            </IconContext.Provider>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </>
                        ) : (
                            <>
                                <div className='z-30'>
                                    <div className='bg-transparent absolute right-4 top-auto mt-3 mr-12 h-auto max-h-full w-auto'>
                                        <button
                                            type='button'
                                            className='bg-white border mr-2 align-top'
                                            title='Recarregar pontos de sondagem'
                                        >
                                            <IconContext.Provider
                                            value={{
                                            color: '#000000',
                                            className: 'h-8 sm:h-10 w-8 sm:w-10',
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        <AiOutlineReload />
                                    </IconContext.Provider>
                                        </button>
                                        <button
                                            type='button'
                                            className='bg-white border'
                                            onClick={handleOpenSlider}
                                        >
                                            <IconContext.Provider
                                                value={{
                                                    color: '#000000',
                                                    className: 'h-12 sm:h-14 w-12 sm:w-14',
                                                }}
                                            >
                                                <AiOutlineLeft />
                                            </IconContext.Provider>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </>
                        )}
                    </>
                )}
                {pointDataArray ? (
                    <>
                        <div className='z-30'>
                            <div className='bg-white absolute sm:right-0 h-auto max-h-full sm:h-full sm:w-1/3 overflow-y-scroll'>
                                <PointData pointDataArray={pointDataArray} distance={distanceBetween} handleClosePointData={handleClosePointData} map={map} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </>
                ) : (null)}
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

function addMarkers(
    map: google.maps.Map | undefined,
    reports: GeoReport[],
    thisMarkers: google.maps.Marker[],
    setThisMarkers: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<google.maps.Marker[]>>,
    setPointDataArray: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<GeoReport | null>>,
) {

    let isVisited = false;

    const markers = reports.map((report: GeoReport) => {

        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: report.lat, lng: report.lng },
            map: map,
            icon: Icon,
        });

        marker.addListener('click', () => {
            isVisited = !isVisited;
            if (isVisited === true) {
                setPointDataArray(report);
            }
        });

        thisMarkers.push(marker);
        setThisMarkers([...thisMarkers]);

        new MarkerClusterer({
            markers: thisMarkers,
            map,
            algorithm: new SuperClusterAlgorithm({ radius: 200 }),
        });

        return marker;
    });
}

const addCircles = (
    map: google.maps.Map | undefined,
    setPointDataArray: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<GeoReport | null>>,
    reports: GeoReport[], circles: google.maps.Circle[],
    setCircles: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<google.maps.Circle[]>>,
) => {

    let isVisited = false;
    const addresses: string[] = [];

    reports.map((report: GeoReport) => {

        report.surveys.map(survey => {
            survey.table.map(data => {
                addresses.push(data.soilType);
            });
        });

        let color = '#FFFFFFF';
        const soilType = findMode(addresses);
        if (soilType) {
            color = getSoilTypeColor(soilType);
        }
        const marker = new google.maps.Circle({
            center: { lat: report.lat, lng: report.lng },
            radius: 500,
            strokeColor: color,
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: color,
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map,
        });

        marker.addListener('click', () => {
            isVisited = !isVisited;
            if (isVisited === true) {
                setPointDataArray(report);
            }
        });

        circles.push(marker);
        setCircles([...circles]);
        return marker;
    });
};

export default TestMap;
```

You can see [here](https://clipchamp.com/watch/i2ri3Go4WTS?utm_source=share&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=watch) what I'm referring to! (I'm refreshing the website so it shows the problem)

Here's a running example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/SleftyLda/helica_frontend/draft/wispy-bash?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A3%2C4-4%2C1&workspaceId=e2383f0f-572e-45ee-aca9-f40a3895da57&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb2pgr30006356hwejr6jat%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb2pgr30002356hqf9co6ax%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb2pgr30004356h8x20kzrf%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb2pgr30005356hkj1mgexy%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B42.6422686338379%252C57.3577313661621%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqb2pgr30002356hqf9co6ax%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb2pgr30001356hrf2a2ke8%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb3tj550002356hqoxujhsz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A3%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A4%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A4%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A1%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb2pgr30002356hqf9co6ax%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqb3tj550002356hqoxujhsz%2522%257D%252C%2522clqb2pgr30005356hkj1mgexy%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb2pgr30005356hkj1mgexy%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqb3989r00qa356h93yum6e0%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb2pp240045356hwuae7w25%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb3989r00qa356h93yum6e0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clqb2pgr30004356h8x20kzrf%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb2pgr30003356hpxid2gfw%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clqb3ecyj0006dqg0ah06bobq%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqb2pgr30004356h8x20kzrf%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqb2pgr30003356hpxid2gfw%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Would you be able to create a *runnable* [mcve] so the bug could be reproduced and debugged? If you need a node-like online editor, use codesandbox.io or similar.

Comment: I'll try! Thanks for the link. Would it be enough to check it online? It's on https://www.dadosdosolo.com/

Comment: not really. The thing about a sandbox is one can also change the code and attempt to find a fix, which is not possible on a live website. Also, in the video you made you seem to refresh very fast. If the bug is that the markers do not appear at the same time as the rest of the map, it's not a bug. That's normal. The map gets initialised without the markers. The markers are loaded separately and, when the request resolves, they're added to the map. If you want to wait for the markers to load and then render the map, you need to share more details about how you're loading the markers data.

Comment: But this won't make the markers load faster. They will take the same amount the time. They will only delay the rendering of the base layer of the map. From UX perspective, that's worse, because you leave the user waiting for a longer time before they can see anything rendered, whereas while they wait for the markers to load they see the map being rendered, it's a better experience and you'll have a smaller bounce rate.

Comment: thanks @tao. I'll work on the live demo. I refreshed quickly but even if it's slow the issue is there. Sometimes when I open the website the markers won't be loaded. The markers are obtained via fetch of a DB that has the locations.

Comment: In that case you want to open the browser console, on the Network tab. Most likely, when the markers don't load, you'll see an error in that tab, which will give you more details about what went wrong. If that's not enough info for you to pinpoint the problem, you should at least add the error message to the question.

Comment: Another possible cause might be you're requesting too much data. This is a pretty complex issue, solved by either clustering the data below a zoom level of choice or by disabling the layer when the map is too zoomed out and only loading that data when the user zooms in (and the requested bounding box is smaller). Hope that makes sense. Anyway, without a runnable example, I'm only speculating in the dark here.

Comment: @tao for checking the network tab on dev tools I've noticed that either the image for the markers doesn't appear listed (and there are no markers on the map) or if appears the status is 200 OK (from memory cache) - I'd think it's best for it to be always loaded via server and never cache - I'll try to prevent cache

Comment: @tao I added the working example to the post. If you could have a look around and provide any help I would be super thankful!

Comment: That's a private repo. You need to invite me (`andrei-gheorghiu` on github) before I could take a look.

Comment: @tao I added you! :)

Comment: I tried to run the repo locally, using my own Maps key. However, I can't see anything on the map as I don't have the backend. It appears your app is making two calls (to `/api/driveimage/getimg` and to `process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND + '/api/report'`) to get whatever is displayed on the map. Since I don't have the backend running, there's no way I can see what's wrong. One way to go around this is to save the response from each of the calls into some json files and add them as static files to the project and then I can run the map and see the contents.

Comment: Anyway, what I understand from your question is that the backend API is not consistent, as in, sometimes calling it does not yield the expected result. I have no way of helping you with that. Besides, you're sharing here how you're consuming the data, which is completely irrelevant. It's like you want to make a soup and you need potatoes. And you go to the store but they don't always have potatoes. And then you ask on a forum: *"Hey guys, here's my soup recipe. Why doesn't it always work?"*

Comment: @tao for what I understand there doesn't seem to be a problem with the fetch because the reports are always fetched, but the markers associated with the reports don't always load - so I think my backend is reliable, that's why I only added the frontend. I updated codesandbox to have the necessary values for the markers but the problem still exists.
The only way the markers always appear is if I have devtools open. I think maybe there's some issue with cache or network request, but couldn't figure it out yet. Thanks for your help

Comment: If backend is reliable, replacing it with a `.json` file should still display the issue. Thanks for adding it, I'll have a look.